# Airdrop won't send files, says recipient has declined request

Tags: airdrop

Airdrop on my 8mth old iMac has stopped sending docs through airdrop. It can receive ok but when trying to send it comes back with a message saying recipient has declined the request. No messages are being received by the recipient or any actions being made.

Apple won't help unless I pay £35!!!!!

Any else experienced this?

Comment: Who is the recipient? try sending it to your self!

Comment: looks like problem on recipient side... as always reboot both machines to see if it is glitch or setup problem... PS Airdrop need to be visible on receiving computers FInder,  and it need to be selected.   But you probably know that since you can receive.

Comment: I'm sending from my iMac to my Macbook Air as well as my wifes Macbook pro. Everything works as it should until I try and send to either of them. I have identified that if I log off as myself and log on as an alternative user, it works fine. So hardware is all ok.

Comment: Having similar problem. Can’t airdrop between two iPhone8s. Both have AirDrop on “everyone”. Both on Wi-Fi. Both have Bluetooth “ON”
Have tried rebooting both ... no joy.